# How does the UserData plugin get the correct value?

Tags: views, entities

The User module defines a `UserData` plugin for the Views module, which allows to access the user.data service from a view. Its [`render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21UserData.php/function/UserData%3A%3Arender/8.4.x) method contains the following code.

```
$uid = $this->getValue($values);
$data = $this->userData->get($this->options['data_module'], $uid, $this->options['data_name']);

// Don't sanitize if no value was found.
if (isset($data)) {
  return $this->sanitizeValue($data);
}
```

}

How does the Views module know the plugin require a user ID? In other words, how does the Views module know that is a field plugin associated with the *User* entity and not another entity?

The annotation for the plugin is simply the following one.

```
@ViewsField("user_data")
```

Neither its [`create()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21UserData.php/function/UserData%3A%3Acreate/8.4.x) nor its [constructor](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21UserData.php/function/UserData%3A%3A__construct/8.4.x) method set something that would make clear to which entity the plugin is associated.

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
  return new static($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $container->get('user.data'), $container->get('module_handler'));
}
```

```
public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, UserDataInterface $user_data, ModuleHandlerInterface $module_handler) {
  parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);

  $this->userData = $user_data;
  $this->moduleHandler = $module_handler;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available fields for the user entity are defined in [Drupal\user\UserViewsData::getViewsData()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21UserViewsData.php/function/UserViewsData%3A%3AgetViewsData/8.3.x):

```
$data['users']['data'] = [
  'title' => $this->t('Data'),
  'help' => $this->t('Provides access to the user data service.'),
  'real field' => 'uid',
  'field' => [
    'id' => 'user_data',
  ],
];
```

This attaches the field `user_data` to the user entity.

Comment: And it defines it as an *alias* of the uid field; that is why it is getting the user ID that is then used to retrieve the data using the *user.data* service.